# Jest / React - How to test the results of useState state update in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jestjs

I have a simple cart function that, when a user clicks to increase or decrease the quantity of an item in a shopping cart, calls a useState function to update the cart quantity in state.

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

const onUpdateItemQuantity = (cartItem, quantityChange) => {
    const newCart = [...cart];
    const shouldRemoveFromCart = quantityChange === -1 && cartItem.count === 1;
    ...
    if (shouldRemoveFromCart) {
      newCart.splice(cartIndex, 1);
    } else {
      ...
    }
    setCart(newCart); //the useState function is called
}
```

so in jest, I have a function that tests when a user sets a cart item's quantity to zero, but it does not yet remove the item from the cart, I'm assuming because it has not yet received the results of `setCart(newCart)`:

```
test('on decrement item from 1 to 0, remove from cart', () => {
      const [cartItemToDecrement] = result.current.cartItems;
      const productToDecrement = result.current.products.find(
        p => p.id === cartItemToDecrement.id
      );

      act(() => {
        result.current.decrementItem(cartItemToDecrement);
      });

      act(() => {
        result.current.decrementItem(cartItemToDecrement);
      });

      ...

      expect(result.current.cartItems).toEqual(
        expect.arrayContaining([
          expect.objectContaining({
            id: cartItemToDecrement.id,
            count: cartItemToDecrement.count - 2,
            inventory: productToDecrement.inventory + 2
          })
        ])
      ); 
    });
  });
```

This test passes, because the cart now contains an item whose quantity has dropped to zero. But really it shouldn't, because from the `splice` operation in `onUpdateItemQuantity` our `cartItems` array should now not include the object at all. How do I verify in my jest test that this removal is happening (the react code works properly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing for state changes is a challenge, because it doesn't produce any specific output (except whatever impacts your render).

The key is to narrow the testing scope to your responsibilities, versus testing React. React is responsible for making sure that `useState` updates the state properly. Your responsibility is to make sure you are using the data properly and sending the correct data back. So instead of testing `useState`, test how your component responds to the state it is given, and make sure you are setting the correct state.

The answer to to mock `useState`. Give it an implementation that returns the initial value passed to it, with a mock function that lets you read what data is being saved.

More detailed answer here:

https://dev.to/theactualgivens/testing-react-hook-state-changes-2oga

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand the relation between the test and your `onUpdateItemQuantity` very much because the context you provided is not sufficient to me.

But from your question, there are 2 clues which may help to save your time.

1. You may know `setCart` from `useState` is not synchronous, so that if you try to access `cart` from `useState` at the same frame, it shouldn't reflect the change even though you ensure `setCart` called. `useEffect` is a good solution. You can find the doc of `useEffect` [https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html][1], any change should be reflected in `useEffect`, perhaps you can put your test there.
2. Add an extra variable `myCart` to store `cart` and a function `setMyCart`. Instead of calling `setCart` in your code, call `setMyCart`. `setMyCart` is like,

```
  function setMyCart(newCart)
  {
     myCart = newCart;
     setCart(myCart); // this is for triggering React re-render
  }
```

then use `myCart` which can reflect the change immediately for testing.

The only purpose of the additional code in the 2nd point, is when we still rely on the re-render mechanism of React, we use our own `Model` `myCart` for our particular logic rather than `cart` state from React which is not only for `View` but also used for our logic on an inappropriate occasion.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally unclear how `onUpdateItemQuantity` is called. And even what it does exactly. Never the less, you claim that `toEqual(...[{...,count:cartItemToDecrement.count - 2,...}]...)` passes. That probably means that `onUpdateItemQuantity` is called inside of `decrementItem`, inside of `onUpdateItemQuantity` there is something like `newCart[cartIndex].count--`, and if `toEqual()` passes, that means that `setState()` successfully updates the state, and after `act()` **you have the actualized state**. And **if test's name is correct** and initial value of `cartItemToDecrement.count === 1` that should mean that `cartItemToDecrement.count - 2 === -1` and you never go inside of `if (shouldRemoveFromCart)`. So maybe the issue is not with the test, but with the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test every state update using useState(), you can do so by implementing a useEffect function that listens specifically for that state change, in your case, cart:

```
useEffect(() => {
    test(...)
), [cart]);
```

And so you can do the test inside the useEffect() function.

That will ensure that you have the correct value of cart and it will be called every time cart is updated.